# How a parachain will connect to polkadot relaychain when the hundred parachain limit is reached?

Tags: relay-chain

There is a limitation of polkadot, such that a total of 100 slots for parachains. I have following questions:

1. How many slots are auctioned till date?
2. How a parachain will connect to polkadot relaychain once this limit is reached? Is there any option other than para threads?
3. Is this not a very serious limitation of polkadot?

Comment: Can you reference where you got this 100 slot limitation from?

Comment: Here is the reference please: https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-parachains

Comment: Yeah someone just pulled that 100 out of their ass.  We've never had a 100 parachains limit of any form.  Only the limit on the number of slots rented out thus far.

Comment: You are right Jeff, but I am not referring "Someone"  here. I am referring polkadot wiki that as per my knowledge is maintained by polkadot/parity team. Please correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no hundred parachain limit in polkadot.  We do not know the limits right now because our code still needs many optimizations.

We've testnets which ran the equivalent of 100 parachains (50% gluttons) on 200 validators, so one parachain per two validators.  I'd expect 500 parachains on kusama's 1000 validators, once we optimize the approval system messages, but real networking conditions could still pose problems of course.

---

All distributed systems have a limited validator set size, due to gossip being quadratic.  We've shown kusama works with enough validators to scale by multiple relay chains, ala [OmniLedger by BryanFord, et al](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/406).  It demands stronger honesty assumptions, which makes the whole decentralization by capitalism business dubious, but it'd gives basically unlimited scalability in theory.

As a comparison, cosmos chain have never run with enough validators for OmniLedger style scaling.  ETH runs more than enough validators, but largely duplicates, which breaks the model, and their networking likely breaks assumptions too.

Answer (score 0):

There is a few different answers to this. First, with asynchronous backing coming out it could theoretically be 1000 blockchains. With 2.0 it could be many many more. But the big thing to remember is when you say "projects" you are saying parachains. A parachain is an L1 Blockchain. If you look at the top 100 projects on coin market cap there isn't  even 100 blockchains in that list. To have 100 blockchains where each Blockchain has its own projects being built on it is a lot of Blockchains. Imagine an ecosystem that has 100 different ethereums. I think a lot of people keep confusing the fact that these are blockchains and not just projects on a blockchain. So each parchain could have thousands of projects built on it. That's already a ton of potential room for a ton of projects.